# Changes made by an IndexWriter are not reflected by an IndexReader

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

I have an `IndexReader` in read only mode, an `IndexSearcher` based on this reader and an `IndexWriter` working on the same Lucene index. I want to delete a document from the index. Afterwards I don't want the document to show up in results returned by the `IndexSearcher` (that's what deletion is about, I suppose). Here is the code:

```
_enIndexWriter.DeleteDocuments(query);
_enIndexWriter.Commit();
_enIndexReader.Reopen();
_enIndexSearcher = new IndexSearcher(_enIndexReader);
```

However, deleted documents are still returned as results, until everything is restarted, i.e. writer, reader and searcher are re-instantiated. Also, it doesn't work to sort out deleted document in the query like this:

```
if (_enIndexReader.IsDeleted(documentId)) continue;
```

The documents which were deleted still return `false` for `IndexReader.IsDeleted(Document)`.

How can I reflect the changes made by the `IndexWriter` in the `IndexSearcher`/`IndexReader` at minimal computational cost? Reinstantiating everything after a deletion is not an option.

I use Lucene.NET v4.0.30319.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it. `IndexReader.Reopen()` returns a reopened instance of the reader on which the method was called, while this stays as it is. Thus, the code needs to be modified like this:

```
_enIndexWriter.DeleteDocuments(query);
_enIndexWriter.Commit();
_enIndexReader = _enIndexReader.Reopen();
_enIndexSearcher = new IndexSearcher(_enIndexReader);
```